# How to Redefine CSS Custom Property Value for :Root Within Container Query Body?

Tags: css, css-variables, container-queries

I'm trying to set a CSS custom property within the `:root` and then change the value depending on the container's size using a container query, but it's not working. Here's an example:

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="test">
    Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

With these styles:

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: red;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  :root {
    --bg-color: green; /* This doesn't seem to do anything. */
  }
  .test {
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
}

.my-container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.test {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

On a larger screen (500px or wider), I would expect the `.test` element with have a green background color, but instead it is red.

The black border is there just to confirm the container query is doing something at all.

In other words, I would expect this:

[image: Green Background]

But I actually get this instead:

[image: Red Background]

I'm using Chrome 120 (also tried latest Firefox). I tried a number of variations that didn't seem to change the outcome (e.g., invert container/root hierarchy, use `html` instead of `:root`, use a named container, and so on). I think using `.test` instead of `:root` for the selector within the container query body did actually work, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish as my use case is to make something reusable.

**Any idea why I can't get this background color to change to green on a larger screen via this altered CSS custom property value within a container query body?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `:root` is not a descendant of `.my-container`, so `@container (...) { :root {...}` matches nothing.

In fact, since `:root` cannot be a descendant of another element, and selectors in container queries are always scoped to the container it can never match inside a container query.

So you have to redefine the `--bg-color` to an element inside the container if your rule is inside that `@container`.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it does seem to be true, so thank you for the insight.

Answer (score -2):

You can override the property value inside the scope of a selected element. See:

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: red;
}

@container (min-width: 500px) {
  .test {
    --bg-color: green;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
  }

}

.my-container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.test {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="test">
    Testing
  </div>
</div>
```